# Node environment variable not being read as string in app

Tags: node.js

I'm using a library that requires a secret string. I've set my node variable like so:

```
export JWT_SECRET=e177920e88165bd0090b1c6b544cf7
```

However, when I try to use it in my app, like so:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

function userToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign({
    user: user.id,
  }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
}
```

it hits an error that says the secret must be a string or buffer. I thought node variables are strings, so not sure what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: for setting enviroment variable in nodejs try this : `process.env['VARIABLE'] = 'value';` as you in this code vlaue should be define as string

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, this works fine for me. Maybe try adding a `console.log(process.env.JWT_SECRET)` to check that your env var is being loaded correctly.

As a side note, I would also consider using some kind of environment variable management library such as [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). It allows you to store a all of your environment variables in a `.env` file like:

```
JWT_SECRET="abc"
OTHER_ENV_VAR="def"
```

It makes it much easier to keep track of your env vars :)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to use the same terminal you exported the environment variable out of.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting envoirment variable like this

process.env['JWT_SECRET'] = 'e177920e88165bd0090b1c6b544cf7';

Or like This:

```
var envs = require('envs');

// If NODE_ENV is not set, 
// then this application will assume it's prod by default.
app.set('environment', envs('NODE_ENV', 'production')); 

// Usage examples:
app.set('ga_account', envs('GA_UA'));
app.set('nr_browser_key', envs('NEW_RELIC_BROWSER_KEY'));
app.set('other', envs('SOME_OTHER_TOKEN));
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so realized that I had a few different windows opened for my terminal. I had to set the variable within the window that I was running application in, in order to get access to `process.env.JWT_SECRET`.